# Solving not exact differential equation $(x^2+y^2+y)dx-xdy=0$ (Riccati type?)

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

here is the diffeq:
$$(x^2+y^2+y)dx-xdy=0$$
I only know how to solve non-exact equations like this when I can solve for a single variate integrating factor.

I think this is a Riccati type equation, but I am hoping to find some solutions that don't involve memorizing this type of equation (or learning from you all that it is really worth memorizing Riccati type equations).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$(x^2+y^2+y)\space\text{d}x-x\space\text{d}y=0\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$(x^2+y^2+y)\space\text{d}x=x\space\text{d}y\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$x^2+y(x)^2+y(x)-xy'(x)=0\Longleftrightarrow$$

---

Let $y(x)=xr(x)$ which gives $y'(x)=r(x)+xr'(x)$:

---

$$x^2-x\left(xr'(x)+r(x)\right)+x^2r(x)^2+xr(x)=0\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$x^2\left(1+r(x)^2-r'(x)\right)=0\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$r'(x)=r(x)^2+1\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$\frac{r'(x)}{r(x)^2+1}=1\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$\int\frac{r'(x)}{r(x)^2+1}\space\text{d}x=\int1\space\text{d}x\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$\arctan(r(x))=x+\text{C}\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$\arctan\left(\frac{y(x)}{x}\right)=x+\text{C}$$

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. Is this the method found here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riccati_equation ? edit: I can see that yes it is, so I assume it is just worth having this tool under my belt?

Comment: @qbert You're welcome, I am glad that I could help you! Yes it is, it is a worth having tool

Comment: Last question: are there any assumptions other than the obvious one (that y(x)=x*r(x)$ with $r(x)\in C^1$ I should be aware of? edit: last last question, what tips you off that this method might be useful, anything to keep an eye out for?

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

$$\dfrac{d(y/x)}{dx}=?$$

Comment: If you scale the equation: $x \to x_{1}$ and $y \to y_{1}$; the equation is invariant whenever ${y \over x} = {y_{1} \over x_{1}}$. That suggests the change ${y \over x} = u$ what it was you already did it. The method is explained in the book "Applications of Lie Groups to Difference Equations" by Vladimir Dorodnitsyn. Chapman & Hall/CRC 2011.